# Генерация больших чисел

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа

Суть вопроса заключается в генерации 8-ми значных чисел без повторов. Для этого я пытаюсь использовать код:

```
import random

a = list(range(10000000, 99999999))
random.shuffle(a)
for b in a:
    print(b)
```

При запуске компилятор не подает признаков жизни и не выводит никакие числа на экран. Прошу подсказать, в чем кроется проблема.

Comment: Создать список из 90 миллионов восьмизначных чисел, а потом их перемешать - это нелёгкая задача. Вам обязательно нужно получить все 90 миллионов сразу?

Comment: На моём компьютере shuffle занял чуть больше минуты

Comment: ...и скушал три гигабайта оперативки. Пропажа признаков жизни может быть в том числе от того, что список всех чисел не влезает память

Comment: @andreymal да все так и получилось, но нужное решение уже найдено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужно какое конкретное количество (например, 10) не повторяющихся чисел, то их можно добыть так:

```
print(random.sample(range(10000000, 99999999), 10))
```

Comment: удивительно быстро работает, похоже не создает list/set внутри.

Answer (score 1):

> в чем кроется проблема.

возможно в том что random.shuffle() очень медленный на массиве с 90 млн значений.

Что вы собираетесть делать с ними дальше?
Вам важно, чтобы каждое число было в списке и встречалось строго один раз, или достаточно просто несколько случайных чисел? с последним справится int(random.uniform(10000000, 99999999)).